# Unable to use `read` command in .ssh/rc

Tags: linux, ssh, sshd, bashrc

I want to read input from keyboard when SSH connection established. So I edited `.ssh/rc` file and used `read` command, just like:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

read -p "input: " something
echo $something
```

But the output is blank; the `read` command does not work.

However, this can normally work when put in `.bashrc` file. How could I use `read` command in `.ssh/rc` file?

Comment: I answered your explicit question but maybe using `read` in `~/.ssh/rc` is not the best way to do whatever you want to do. Compare [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310). You got answer to Y, so the question shouldn't be substantially changed now, even if there's X behind it. Still you can ask a separate question about X, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

`man 8 sshd` in my Debian reads [emphasis mine]:

> `If ~/.ssh/rc` exists and the `sshd_config(5)` `PermitUserRC` option is set, runs it; else if `/etc/ssh/sshrc` exists, runs it; otherwise runs `xauth`. **The “rc” files are given the X11 authentication protocol and cookie in standard input.**
>
> […]
>
> If the file `~/.ssh/rc` exists, `sh(1)` runs it after reading the environment files but before starting the user's shell or command. It must not produce any output on stdout; stderr must be used instead. If X11 forwarding is in use, it will receive the "proto cookie" pair in its standard input (and `DISPLAY` in its environment). The script must call `xauth(1)` because `sshd` will not run `xauth` automatically to add X11 cookies.

Even if X11 forwarding is not in use, your `read` doesn't interact with what you type because stdin is taken from elsewhere. (Note in addition `echo` prints to stdout, while it shouldn't).

If you request X11 forwarding (and all is set right for it to work), your `read` will indeed read something and `echo` will print something. Try it (`ssh -X the_server`). Example output:

```
MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 d936faac03ac21db21160fb6cab5be86
```

And if you add `ls -l /proc/$$/fd/` to the script then it will show you the file descriptor `0` (stdin) is not what you expected. Example:

```
lr-x------ 1 kamil kamil 64 May  5 12:03 0 -> pipe:[5335679]
lrwx------ 1 kamil kamil 64 May  5 12:03 1 -> /dev/pts/4
lrwx------ 1 kamil kamil 64 May  5 12:03 2 -> /dev/pts/4
lr-x------ 1 kamil kamil 64 May  5 12:03 3 -> /proc/13928/fd
```

<sup>In case you don't know: `0` is stdin, `1` is stdout, `2` is stderr.</sup>

You can make `read` interact with the TTY:

```
</dev/tty read -p "input: " something
echo "$something" >&2
```

Notes:

- The shebang you used is irrelevant, `sshd` uses `sh` to run the file regardless.
- In general you should double-quote variables.
- My code prints to stderr, as the manual requested.
- The script doesn't run `xauth`, so you wont be able to forward X11.